# Slice a multidimensional array based on regex in java

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

I have an ArrayList as follows:

```
[Longest Episode    24.9 min, ,  Gastric pH  :  Channel 8,      Bolus Exposure (Impedance) Total,   Total   Normal,  Acid Time  2.9 min ,  Acid Percent Time    1.2%    , Nonacid Time  11.6 min    ,  Nonacid Percent Time 4.8%    ,  All Reflux Time  14.5 min    ,  All Reflux Percent Time  6.1%    ,  Median Bolus Clearance Time  8 sec   ,  Longest Episode  11.2 min]
```

I would like to extract just the elements from `"Bolus Exposure (Impedance) Total"` to `"Longest Episode    11.2 min"` . Because the intervening number of elements changes I can't do this by index alone. How can this be done by regex? Do I have to convert the arrayList into a string and then regex and then back to an ArrayList? Although this doesn't work for me.

```
for (int ff=0;ff<Postprand_arr_table.size();ff++){ 
                     dd=dd+Postprand_arr_table.get(ff)+"_";
                 }

Pattern PPBolusExpo_pattern = Pattern.compile("Bolus Exposure.*?11.2 min");
             Matcher matcherPPBolusExpo_pattern = PPBolusExpo_pattern.matcher(dd);
            ArrayList<String> subbie = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String d:dd.split("_")){
                subbie.add(d);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `RegEx` for a simple string equality check, following should work

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
String startToken = "Bolus Exposure (Impedance) Total";
String endToken = "Longest Episode    11.2 min";
boolean startAdding = false;

for(String element: array) {
    if(startToken.equals(element)) {
        startAdding = true;
    } else if(endToken.equals(element)) {
        newList.add(element);
        break;
    }
    if(startAdding) {
        newList.add(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you are trying to do this in a "Simple" way, but honestly the simplest is just to put it in a separate method and code it up. In this way your calling method is clean and your called method is understandable--what more could the next guy reading your code ask for?

You can just pass in (List, String, String) or you could pass in (List, Matcher, Matcher) if you want to be a little more typesafe (at the cost of slightly more weighty calling code).

You could then just iterate over the string, find the index of the first match and then find the index of the second match and return that slice of the list.  Simple, readable, concise.

Java will probably even optimize away the function call so performance isn't an excuse not to do it the readable/reusable way.

There is probably a continuation/closure-based/functional approach that would do the same thing in one line without an additional method but honestly, it would be less readable to pretty much everyone and, to add insult to injury, your "Slice" code will no longer be Reusable with the closure approach the way a separate method would.

I imagine something like:

```
List<String> slice(List<String> list, Matcher mFirst, Matcher mSecond)
{
    int ixFirst=-1;
    int ixSecond=-1;

    for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++) {
        // Sorry, don't know the matcher syntax off the top of my head
        if(ixFirst != -1 && ixSecond == -1 && mSecond.matches(list.get(i)))
            ixSecond = i;
        if(ixFirst == -1 && mFirst.matches(list.get(i)))
            ixFirst = i;
     }
     if(ixFirst == -1 || ixSecond == -1)
         //throw exception or return null
     return list.substring(ixFirst,ixSecond);
}
```

Since I did that off the top of my head and didn't test it or look anything up I probably got something wrong--in particular I think substring's second parameter is a length not a position which means it should be ixSecond-ixFirst, not just ixSecond...

Anyway, the point is that the above is readable and testable (if a bit longer than necessary) but the calling code is simply:

```
List<String> newList=slice(origList, matcherPPBolusExpo_pattern , longestEpisode_pattern)
```

Which you can easily see and understand when bug-hunting (If not, make the name better!)